# Converting ControlTemplate XAML to C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, frameworkelementfactory

I have been stumped with trying to convert the following code into pure c#.  This XAML code is from Cavanaghs blog on how to make rounded corners on anything.  The code works but I need to convert it to c# as i need it to be dynamic in some cases.  If you could help that would be great.

```
<Setter Property="Template">
<Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType='{x:Type ListViewItem}'>
        <Grid>
            <Border CornerRadius="15" Name="mask" Background="White"/>
            <StackPanel Background="Beige">
                <StackPanel.OpacityMask>
                    <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=mask}"/>
                </StackPanel.OpacityMask>
                <GridViewRowPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Columns="{TemplateBinding GridView.ColumnCollection}"/>
                <TextBlock Background="LightBlue" Text="{Binding News}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Setter.Value>
```

So far I have the following but I am getting errors.

```
FrameworkElementFactory border = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Border));
border.SetValue(Border.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.White);
border.SetValue(Border.CornerRadiusProperty, new CornerRadius(8, 8, 8, 8));
border.SetValue(Border.NameProperty, "roundedMask");
```

As far as I can tell I cant make the VisualBrush as a FrameworkElementFactory (crashes), but if i declare it as a regular element VisualBrush i cant pass border in as a Visual since its a FrameworkElementFactory.

Simply i am getting lost, any help would be appreciated.
Thanks for any help

Comment: You know you can provide a Name to the element in question within XAML then reference it within the code behind to provide the dynamic capability you desire. You do not need to build the entire element within the code behind.

Comment: For future reference, XAML is parsed into C# (or VB in a VB project). After compiling, look in the .obj folder for `MyXamlFile.g.cs`. It contains the parsed code.

Comment: @Tergiver this is not accurate (at least not anymore) - XAML generates .BAML (in WPF) and Codebehind C#/VB etc. code is for assigning the named references to class variables (codebehind is a partial class that complements the BAML)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not want to know this. Seriously, you don't, it's a nightmare.

**Edit:** If i did not make any mistake this is the translation of your code...

```
Setter setter = new Setter();
setter.Property = ListViewItem.TemplateProperty;
ControlTemplate template = new ControlTemplate(typeof(ListViewItem));
var grid = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Grid));
var border = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Border));
border.SetValue(Border.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.White);
border.SetValue(Border.NameProperty, "mask");
border.SetValue(Border.CornerRadiusProperty, new CornerRadius(15));
grid.AppendChild(border);
var stackPanel = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
stackPanel.SetValue(StackPanel.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Beige);
var visualBrush = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(VisualBrush));
visualBrush.SetBinding(VisualBrush.VisualProperty, new Binding() { ElementName = "mask" });
stackPanel.SetValue(StackPanel.OpacityMaskProperty, visualBrush);
var gridViewRowPresenter = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(GridViewRowPresenter));
gridViewRowPresenter.SetValue(GridViewRowPresenter.ContentProperty, new TemplateBindingExtension(GridViewRowPresenter.ContentProperty));
gridViewRowPresenter.SetValue(GridViewRowPresenter.ColumnsProperty, new TemplateBindingExtension(GridView.ColumnCollectionProperty));
stackPanel.AppendChild(gridViewRowPresenter);
var textBlock = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
textBlock.SetValue(TextBlock.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.LightBlue);
textBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("News"));
stackPanel.AppendChild(textBlock);
grid.AppendChild(stackPanel);
template.VisualTree = grid;
setter.Value = template;
```

**Edit:** There is still a bug left, the `VisualBrush` cannot be created like that, the rest seems to work.

Comment: Right, thats what I am stuck on.  It seems you need to create the visualbrush directly ie VisualBrush vbrush = new VisualBrush.  But then I can't pass the border in directly as thats not a visual but a FrameworkElementFactory...  Thats the part that got me stumped... thanks for the help though.

Comment: Stuck in exactly the same place.  There seems to be no logic in the FrameworkFactory for applying child factories to exposed properties.  That might be what the disclaimer about the class being obsolete is all about.  There are various examples showing embedded XAML code, but that has problems also.

Comment: probably they're using a value converter internally, you could try to find which one it is and call it

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis: (The factory approach is deprecated anyway.)

Answer (score 6):

You don't actually have to convert this into C# to apply it dynamically. If you add it to your application resources, within your App.xaml file as follows:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType='{x:Type ListViewItem}' x:Key="MyListViewItemTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Border CornerRadius="15" Name="mask" Background="White"/>
            <StackPanel Background="Beige">
                <StackPanel.OpacityMask>
                    <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=mask}"/>
                </StackPanel.OpacityMask>
                <GridViewRowPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Columns="{TemplateBinding GridView.ColumnCollection}"/>
                <TextBlock Background="LightBlue" Text="{Binding News}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

Note the x:Key attribute which keys this item.

You can then look it up anywhere in your code ...

```
ControlTemplate template = this.Findresource("MyListViewItemTemplate") as ControlTemplate
```

You can then apply it as and when you need it!

Comment: Yes thats true I can do that, but my curiosity gets me and I really want to know how the C# code will look like for this.  I just find it unbelievable how much more difficult it is to do this in code.  Its simply not that obvious sometimes.  Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: there used to be a XamlIt tool from what I've read that should be able to convert such XAML to C#, but can't find it online anymore