# how to convert xaml code to c# code in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

How to covert this xaml code to cs:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="mainsp">    
    <Border Style="{StaticResource bordercss}" >
        <StackPanel x:Name="getme"  Background="White" Orientation="Vertical" d:DataContext="{Binding TaskList[0]}" >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}" Style="{StaticResource btbx_bold}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding csoId}" Style="{StaticResource btbx_new}" />
            <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource btbx_new}" >
                <Run Text="Date : " />
                <Run Text="{Binding mydate}" />
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource btbx_new}"  >
                <Run Text="Status : " />
                <Run Text="{Binding mystatus}" />
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource btbx_new}" >
                <Run Text="Customer Info : " />
                <Run Text="{Binding clientname}" />                        
                <Run Text=" ("/>                    
                <Run Text="{Binding customercontact}" />
                <Run Text=") "/>
            </TextBlock>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="/Assets/address_icon.png" Margin="5,0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding csoId}" Style="{StaticResource btbx_new}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <Line StrokeThickness="2" Fill="Black" Margin="5,0" />
            <Button Content="Get Direction" Background="#B80E0F" Click="Button_Click_1"  FontSize="18"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Check these answers, they worked for me:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726343/converting-controltemplate-xaml-to-c-sharp ///
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930754/convert-xaml-to-c-sharp

Comment: why not use the XAML in the windows Phone? by what I can see your code should work no changes needed.

Comment: i use this not in toottip of map , like binding this data in pushpin

Answer (score 1):

I won't convert the entire code because that will take some time, but you can find everything on MSDN. Here is an example:

```
var stackPanel = new StackPanel();
var border = new Border();
stackPanel.Children.Add(border);

var stackPanel2 = new StackPanel();
border.Content = stackPanel;
```

Etc.

As for binding, see [How to: Create a Binding in Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742863%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Sample:

```
MyData myDataObject = new MyData(DateTime.Now);      
Binding myBinding = new Binding("MyDataProperty");
myBinding.Source = myDataObject;
myText.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, myBinding);
```

Comment: no bro i have problem with databinding

Comment: See my edit for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Thats how

```
StackPanel mainsp=new StackPanel() //main parent

Border bb=new Border()
bb.Style=(Style)App.Current.Resources["bordercss"];
mainsp.Children.Add(bb);

StackPanel getme=new StackPanel();

TextBlock textblock=new TextBlock();
Run myRun=new Run();
myRun.text="Hi";
textblock.inlines.Add(myRun);
getme.Children.Add(textblock);
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need to know is at [XAML Syntax In Detail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788723%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#xaml_content_properties).

The basics are:

Each tag name corresponds to a class name, usually under the `System.Windows.Controls` namespace, and each attribute corresponds to a property (you probably already know this).

Nested elements, unless they are wrapped in a tag specifically pointing to a property (such as `Grid.RowDefinitions`), are assigned to the property specified by [ContentPropertyAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.contentpropertyattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the class for the containing tag. If it's a collection type then each nested element is added to it. For example, on [TextBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)'s declaration you can see `[ContentPropertyAttribute("Inlines")]`, so your `TextBlock` containing `Runs` translates to:

```
var tb = new TextBlock();
var run1 = new Run();
var run2 = new Run();
tb.Inlines.Add(run1);
tb.Inlines.Add(run2);
```

[FindResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findresource.aspx) gets the value for a resource  key at an element's scope. Calling this as you initialize an element is the equivalent of `StaticResource`. For `DynamicResource`, use [SetResourceReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.setresourcereference%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

[SetBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.setbinding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) applies a binding to a property.

Thus the complete translation for the above `TextBlock` would be:

```
var tb = new TextBlock();
tb.Style = (Style)tb.FindResource("btbx_new");
var run1 = new Run {Text = "Date : "};
var run2 = new Run();
run2.SetBinding(Run.TextProperty, "mydate");
tb.Inlines.Add(run1);
tb.Inlines.Add(run2);
```