# How do I convert this xaml to C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

how can i do the below xaml in c#. i know how to create gridview and columns by c# but for this one i dont know where to start.

```
<ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="309" Margin="90,61,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="551">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="100">
                        <GridViewColumn.Header>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <TextBlock>Header</TextBlock>
                                <ComboBox Width="92">
                                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Filter Item 1" />
                                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Filter Item 2" />
                                </ComboBox>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </GridViewColumn.Header>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: The same way you do any other xaml in C#.  You build up the same objects that the xaml would, but using the `new` keyword, and you set the properties just as the xaml would.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4727928/102937) for an example conversion.

Answer (score -1):

To create a `GridView`:

```
var gv = new GridView();
```

To add columns to the `GridView`:

```
var gvCol = new GridViewColumn();
gv.Columns.Add(gvCol);
```

To set the `Header` on the `GridViewColumn`:

```
gvCol.Header = new StackPanel();
```

And continue the rest programmatically.